# List bullet missing with code block as the first paragraph of a list (Chrome 12)

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, markdown-rendering

With a code block as the first paragraph of a list item, the list bullet goes missing in Chrome 12.

With this markdown

```
Ordered list:

 1. <pre><code>test</code></pre>

Unordered list:

 *  <pre><code>test</code></pre>

As second paragraph, it's fine:

 *  first paragraph

        second paragraph
```

I see this result in Chrome 12.0.742.112.

[image: the bullet points are missing]

The generated HTML looks correct, so I'm assuming this is a CSS issue. I've checked in Firefox 5.0 and there it looks fine.

Comment: Works just fine when you use the correct markdown syntax, instead of HTML tags... Like most of these bugs.

Comment: The missing numbers [of your Sandbox post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/99650#99650) (2. and 5. in the first list, and 1. in the second list) do [show in my Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hxf5i.png) (though a bit ugly). But [not in my Chrome and Safari](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qB6q2.png), on a Mac.

Comment: @Cody: What would the correct markdown syntax for this be? I've [tried a few ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/99650#99650) that either result in a missing bullet or no code formatting.

Comment: Hm, this seems like a WebKit rendering bug. The numbers aren't appearing because of the `overflow: auto` on the `<pre>` blocks, but there's not any reason I can think of that that should make sense.

Comment: @Tim: This seems to be correct. I can reproduce the problem with [this minimal example](http://pastebin.com/fY42Amne).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suspected, this is [indeed a WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13332), and apparently a long-outstanding one at that. They used `overflow: hidden` in the test case, but it appears to happen for any value of overflow besides visible. I'll see if I can come up with a suitable workaround, but if not I don't think there's much that can be done from this end.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different ways to do this in markdown that will work on any browser:

---

Ordered list:

1. `test`

Unordered list:

- `test`

As second paragraph, it's fine:

- first paragraph

  ```
  second paragraph
  ```

***First Approach:*** You use backticks to indicate that the first two lines are inline code snippets. You don't get syntax highlighting this way, but you don't get that with `<pre>` and `<code>` tags anyway.

---

Ordered list:

1. ```
   test
   ```

Unordered list:

- ```
  test
  ```

As second paragraph, it's fine:

- first paragraph

  ```
  second paragraph
  ```

***Second Approach:*** You use either a string of regular (non-code) text, or a literal space character (`&nbsp;`) or equivalent, to make the list item show up, then you indent the code block using **8** spaces starting on the next line.

*The advantage here is that you get syntax highlighting for the code block and it is a lot easier to read. The obvious disadvantage is that it will not be displayed on the same line as the number/bullet. It's still just below the number/bullet, though, and obviously associated with it, so this achieves very much the same general effect as the first approach.*