# What happened to the numbers in my ordered list?

Tags: support, bug, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List bullet missing with code block as the first paragraph of a list (Chrome 12)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99651/list-bullet-missing-with-code-block-as-the-first-paragraph-of-a-list-chrome-12)

On my [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11036124/561731) I made an ordered list like so:

```
  1. 

        function foo(){
             alert('BAR');
        }

  2. 

        var foo = function (){
             alert('BAR');
        }

  3. 

        var foo = function bar(){
             alert('BAR');
        }
```

But it shows up with **no numbers** in the list!

[image: no numbers?]

### What happened?!

Comment: Ordered lists don't work in code formatting.  Your 1. and 2.  aren't part of any language that I know of.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it does create the `<ol>` if you look at the output.

Comment: Break the code up into separate code formatting blocks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean?

Comment: They seriously haven't fixed this bug yet? What the hell Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the indent from the numeric list elements.

1. ```
       function foo(){
            alert('BAR');
       }
   ```
2. ```
       var foo = function (){
            alert('BAR');
       }
   ```
3. ```
       var foo = function bar(){
            alert('BAR');
       }
   ```

Comment: I want the numbered list. 1,2,3 -- they are example numbers

Comment: You don't seen them in my example above?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I dont (on Chrome)

Comment: @Robert... I see [none](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9cMrA.png) :-( [I am in Chrome]

Comment: I see them in the stock Android browser. (2.3)