# How can I start a list item with a code block?

Tags: support, markdown

I'm aware that I can do this:

1. This code is python:

   ```
   print "Hello"
   print "World"
   ```
2. And this is javascript:

   ```
   console.log("Hello")
   console.log("World")
   ```

But is it possible to correctly format this?

1. print "Hello"
       print "World"

   That code was python
2. console.log("Hello")
       console.log("World")

   And that was javascript

Which I've marked up as:

```
1.      print "Hello"
        print "World"

    That code was python

2.      console.log("Hello")
        console.log("World")

    And that was javascript
```

Currently, my attempts either:

- Drop the numbering for no obvious reason
- Result in a blank line before the code block
- Work only for a single line of code using `` ` ``s

Comment: You need a block of code, or a single line? If the latter, just use backticks.

Comment: @bart: Aiming for a block of code, hence me listing `s as a failed attempt. Updated the question to be more clear

Comment: Ah, I glanced over that single character in the last line.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, although it's a bit messy:

1. ```
   print "Hello World"
   ```

   That code was python
2. ```
   console.log("Hello World")
   ```

   And that was javascript

Source:

```
1.  

        print "Hello World"

    That code was python

2. 

        console.log("Hello World")

    And that was javascript
```

However, be aware that WebKit based browsers won't show the list item numbers with this structure, due to a [long-standing bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99651/list-bullet-missing-with-code-block-as-the-first-paragraph-of-a-list-chrome-12/99668#99668). The produced HTML is still as expected, though.

Comment: This was the behaviour I was describing in my first bullet point. I'd assumed it was a quirk in the markdown parser, not my browser's rendering.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's a browser bug that still hasn't been fixed. Probably worth double-checking if there's any way the CSS here could be changed to work around the issue, I'll make a note to meddle with it a bit later.

Comment: Simply unchecking `overflow: auto` for `pre` in the chrome inspector makes this behave for me. Of course, that's there for the scrolling behaviour for large code boxes.

Comment: test-case [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167026/147400)