# List numbers/bullets get skipped when a list item begins with a quote

Tags: bug, markdown, android-app, markdown-rendering

I was just now reading [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50687/1204) on the Android app v1.0.51, and noticed a rendering error in its list styles. Compare the mobile app rendering, which has the **1.** missing before the first list item:

> [image]

To the desktop site which shows where the 1 should be:

> [image]

It seems the mobile app skips list styling for any list item beginning with a quote.

## For more testing/demonstration

View this question in your browser and *most* of these list items will not have a number or a bullet.

### Ordered list

1. > A quote, list item 1.
2. > Another quote, list item 2.
3. > List item that isn't just a quote.

   Normal text too.
4. List item that starts with normal text.

   > and includes a quote.
5. > Spoiler quote, list item 5.

### Unordered list

- > Quote block
- > Spoiler quote block
- > Begins with quote.

  Has normal text too.
- Begins with normal text.

  > Has a quote.

Comment: Hmm, this is *probably* another case of [List bullet missing with code block as the first paragraph of a list (Chrome 12)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99651) specific to the app styling (the question body is rendered with a web view, if I recall correctly)

Comment: The [following answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42705/31503) renders with very mixed results depending on whether it's viewed from firefox, chrome, or the android app. Firefox works, android app 'hides' the numbers, and it's been reported that chrome hides&forgets the numbers (all numbers restart from 1).

Comment: @rolfl currently both desktop Chrome (v39.0.2171.99 m) and Android Chrome (v39.0.2171.93) _and_ the Android app (v1.0.51, Android 4.4.3) are skipping #5 and #7 in that list, and only those. At least it's consistently weird!

Comment: This seems to be better after the M40 WebView update on Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone)'s on the money in the comments. Post rendering in app uses a `WebView` which is based on different versions of WebKit/Chromium depending on what version of Android you're running, I'll leave this question open for now until I find time to investigate a bit more on seeing if we can fix this on our side.

Comment: Urgh, and I might have to finally convince myself to delve into the Blink code to see why that happens. I can't believe (for values of not believing where I am not at all shocked) that it's still not fixed. |:

Comment: I can confirm this bug still occurs on Lollipop (Nexus 7 2012, 5.0.2), so I'm betting as @Tim said, it was never fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is not reproducible on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta), WebView v48.0.2564.85: all numbers were shown correctly on the list with quotation/code block. Unfortunately, I have no clue what's the cause, or who fixed this.

This answer is only for a demonstration that the bug didn't occur on this scenario.

[image: answer on RPG.SE]

<sup>[Answer on RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50687/1204) - quotation case</sup>

[image: test case on this bug report]

<sup>Test case on this bug report - another quotation case</sup>

[image: answer on CR.SE] [image: answer on CR.SE] [image: answer on CR.SE]

<sup>[Answer on CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42705/31503) - code block</sup>

Comment: Kasra suggested in his answer it's because they use WebView (an Android system component), so the answer could've been Google itself fixed their own bug in their system software.